# Chrome/edge browser inspect element tool does not render @media query correctly

Tags: css

I am looking for a solution or answer to an issue I have with the inspect element in chrome. I have a media query that changes the background color when the min-width is equal to 60em. When I go to the inspect element and change the screen size in the browser the change does not happen when the screen size is reduced below 60em. However when I come out of inspect element and in the normal browser and adjust the screen size below 60em the css works and the background color changes as expected.
Thanks

I have tried edge and the same things happens. I expected that when the screen is reduced smaller than 60em it would change to the color specified in the css but it does not it only works when im not in the inspect element but will work in the normal windows browser.

Comment: Can you show an example of this

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi I finally found a way to resolve the issue it was simply to change the device type which was hidden to desktop and the @media queries worked correctly on the inspect element page.